# Can't decide who to award the bounty to, they're all worthy

Tags: discussion, bounties

[I opened a question to bounty](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/228069/call-the-database-every-time-or-create-an-object-in-memory-and-if-so-how-and) on the premise that it "wasn't getting any attention" and now it has gotten a bunch of helpful answers which all help me in some ways making it impossible for me to decide which one to award the bounty to.

Shouldn't there be an option to award the bounty equally among selected answerers, especially in this case where was getting *no* answers whatsoever before the bounty, or am I overthinking it and should award it to the first answer?

Comment: Well it should go to gbjbaanb if you don't do anything. That's the accepted answer.

Comment: If you can't pick, then award one the bounty, and create another bounty to award to the other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't overthink bounties. In the end, it really doesn't quite matter *that* much. You aren't bestowing a Ferrari upon these good folks.

But if you want to you may consult with a dodecagon, and see what number shows up. Good luck!!

But really, doing nothing is a *very* Ok option. It will default and split half the bounty to the top-voting answer ( see - [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work) ) & thanks Jelly . Here are details:

> if the bounty starter accepted an answer during the bounty period, that
>   answer is awarded the bounty. Answers accepted before the bounty
>   period are not eligible to be awarded the bounty automatically.
>
> Otherwise, if there are eligible answers, the highest scoring is
>   awarded half the bounty amount. The criteria for an answer to be
>   eligible are:
>
> ```
> The answer must have been given after the bounty was started
> The answer must have a score of at least +2
> The answer must not have been written by the bounty starter
> ```
>
> If two or more eligible answers have the same score (if their scores
>   are tied), the oldest answer is awarded the bounty.
>
> If neither of these conditions apply, the bounty is not awarded to any
>   answer, and is not refunded to the bounty starter.

EDIT: come on, you have 2 fat answers and 2 measly answers. Pick one of the 1st two - psr or gbjsanbh2